# Error while fetching an parse class column in NSArray in my ios app

Tags: parse-platform, nsarray, pfquery

Need Help!!!

Guys, i am using Parse for cloud data backend for my app. Have a parse class with column type as file. It stores images. In my application i need to fetch all images available in this column and store in a array.

Next is the error and code sample. Per my understanding it fails on findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock.
Please help

Error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'This query has an outstanding network connection. You have to wait until it's done.’

Code:

- (PFQuery *)queryForTable
  {
  NSLog(@"queryForTable ***ENTER** ");

  PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
  [query whereKey:TAB_PARSE_WHERE_KEY equalTo:self.tShelfID];

  // If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache first to fill the table
  // and then subsequently do a query against the network.
  if ([self.objects count] == 0) {
      query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
  }

  NSLog(@"queryForTable *** 1 ** ");

  [query cancel]; //cancels the current network request being made by this query (if any)
  [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

  ```
  NSLog(@"queryForTable *** 2 ** ");

  if (!error) {
      // The find succeeded.
      NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved "); 
      //for (PFObject *object in objects) {
          //NSLog(@"INSIDE FOR LOOOP");
          //NSLog(@"%@", object.bookId);
      //}
  } else {
      // Log details of the failure
      NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
  }
  ```

  }];

  //[query orderByAscending:TAB_PARSE_ORDER_KEY];

  NSLog(@"queryForTable ***EXIT** ");
  return query;

}

Answer (score 0):

To download file from parse

First you need to call simple query to download all image reference and then you need to use **PFFile** class of parse.com

Please check out this link : https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFFile.html

You can write below code in some function to download files from parse.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Your Classname"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        for (PFObject *currentObj in objects) {
            PFFile *currentFile = [currentObj objectForKey:@"Your column name in which files are stored"];
            // TO DOWNLOAD SYNCHRONOSLY
            NSData *fileData = [currentFile getData];
            UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:fileData];
            //--------- You can store IMG object ref in your array and display --------//
            //TO DOWNLOAD ASYNCHRONOSLY
            [currentFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                if (!error) {
            //--------- You can store IMG object ref in your array and display --------//
                    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                }
            } progressBlock:^(int percentDone) {
                NSLog(@"Download Complete Percentage");
            }];
        }
    }
}];
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments Malav. I am new to app development. Could you please show me how to implement your suggestion.

Comment: Can you tell me what exactly you are trying to do with parse?
According to your description you want to download files store in some class's column in parse. right?

Comment: Thanks Malav, i have got it now..i was writing it all wrong. 
Now fetching column like this
self.tBookPages = [[object objectForKey:TAB_SEGUE_KEY_Pages] getData];

However, i have still need to figure out how to fetch whole column and store in an array.

Comment: You can not download only one column's data.. as there is no options given by parse yet... You will get all data each row with all column .. so that you have to manage by your own.